# Массив json_decode - элемент значения firm_offer_id

Tags: php, json, foreach

Помогите разобрать массив json_decode. Интересует элемент значения `firm_offer_id`.

```
Array
(
    [0] =>; Array
        (
            [cost] =>; 290
            [firm_offer_id] =>; 52c113
        )

    [1] =>; Array
        (
            [cost] =>; 330
            [firm_offer_id] =>; 53c115
        )

    [2] =>; Array
        (
            [cost] =>; 330
            [firm_offer_id] =>; 54c117
        )

    [3] =>; Array
        (
            [cost] =>; 330
            [firm_offer_id] =>; 40c88
        )

    [4] =>; Array
        (
            [cost] =>; 300
            [firm_offer_id] =>; 57c123
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [
    ["cost" => 330, "firm_offer_id" => "53c115"],
    ["cost" => 330, "firm_offer_id" => "54c117"],
    ["cost" => 330, "firm_offer_id" => "40c88"],
    ["cost" => 300, "firm_offer_id" => "57c123"]
];

foreach ($array as $el) {
    echo $el["firm_offer_id"];
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `array_map`

```
<?php

function mapFn ($item) {
    return $item['firm_offer_id'];
}

$data = [['cost' => 1, 'firm_offer_id' => 2]];
$result = array_map('mapFn', $data);
print_r($result);
```